# Grid CSS Nonconsecutive Cells Explanation

Tags: css, css-grid

I've just started playing with CSS Grid and am unclear about the limitations of the `grid-template-area`, and I cannot find any proper docs/guides about this.

I understand you cannot "tetris" with CSS Grid, but let's look at this simple example for a second:

`grid-template-areas: 
    "h h h h h h"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s f f f f f";`

The `template-columns` and `rows` are just `1fr` all the way, so nothing interesting there, and each element only has a background color. The above works **fine**. However, this does not:

`"h h h h h h"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s f f f . f";`

By "doesn't work" I mean nothing appears on the page.

It's not really tetris; I just want a blank spot in the footer. I understand I cannot do this, but can someone explain the explicit *rules* behind this?

**Edit**
@Michael_B Suggested not tetris *and* connected rectangles, but this matrix also doesn't work:

`"h h h h h h"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s m . . m m"
    "s m m m m m"
    "s f f f f f";`

**Edit 2**
As the other answer says, named grid cells must form a *single* filled-in rectangle; that's the trick.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot have tetris-shaped grid areas (as you noted) *and* grid areas must form a connected rectangle.

Comment: @Michael_B please see the update - all the `m`s are still connected rectangles, and it's not tetris-shaped; I just want two gaps

Comment: @Michael_B just saw you marked this as duplicate and the other answer certainly helps - thanks!